# How to use multiple @RequestMapping annotations in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use multiple `@RequestMapping` annotations over a method?

Like :

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@RequestMapping("")
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public String welcomeHandler(){
  return "welcome";
}
```

Answer (score 535, accepted):

`@RequestMapping` has a `String[]` value parameter, so you should be able to specify multiple values like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value={"", "/", "welcome"})
```

Comment: That said, I'm having trouble getting the "" or "/" values to actually work in my application.  Do they work for you?

Comment: Is there a way to associate different success views and form views with each request URL using multiple annotations?

Comment: @EdBrannin I need many to use, custom, header, consumes, params, etc

Comment: Also I would like to know, how do I know which requestmapping has been called. is it / or welcome ?

Comment: @Siddharth 1. You might be able to add & inspect a parameter of type HttpRequest. 2. If you really care which mapping was called, maybe don't use this technique. ;)

Comment: For all trying to reproduce this in kotlin, you need to use arrayOf or [] instead of the {} syntax.

Answer (score 27):

From my test (spring 3.0.5), `@RequestMapping(value={"", "/"})`  - only `"/"` works, `""` does not. However I found out this works: `@RequestMapping(value={"/", " * "})`, the `" * "` matches anything, so it will be the default handler in case no others.

Answer (score 14):

Doesn't need to.  RequestMapping annotation supports wildcards and ant-style paths.  Also looks like you just want a default view, so you can put

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome"/>
```

in your config file.  That will forward all requests to the Root to the welcome view.

Comment: Is there supposed to be something between those two lines?
I am using the FreeMarkerViewResolver - so I would have to go this way... Well, I guess I could just create multiple ViewResolver.

Comment: It doesn't provide the flexibility that multiple RequestMapping annotations would provide. For example, if I want to have one method support either value "/a" with POST or value "/b" with GET. Of course the workaround is fairly easy (refactoring the functionality in a third method), but just saying that it would be useful.

Answer (score 9):

The shortest way is: `@RequestMapping({"", "/", "welcome"})`

Although you can also do:

- `@RequestMapping(value={"", "/", "welcome"})`
- `@RequestMapping(path={"", "/", "welcome"})`

Answer (score 7):

The following is acceptable as well:

```
@GetMapping(path = { "/{pathVariable1}/{pathVariable1}/somePath", 
                     "/fixedPath/{some-name}/{some-id}/fixed" }, 
            produces = "application/json")
```

Same can be applied to `@RequestMapping` as well

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use PathVariable annotation if you still want to get the uri which was called.

```
@PostMapping("/pub/{action:a|b|c}")
public JSONObject handlexxx(@PathVariable String action, @RequestBody String reqStr){
...
}
```

or parse it from request object.

Answer (score 2):

Right now with using Spring-Boot 2.0.4 - { } won't work.

```
@RequestMapping
```

still has String[] as a value parameter, so declaration looks like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value=["/","/index","/login","/home"], method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

** Update - Works With Spring-Boot 2.2**

```
 @RequestMapping(value={"/","/index","/login","/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: The square brackets is invalid. The valid syntax for an array literal is to use braces {}

Comment: @luis.espinal Square brackets worked with 2.0.4 Spring-Boot version. I will update my post.