# Get requested value(URL) when using @RequestMapping annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I map multiple values to @RequestMapping(like [Multiple Spring @RequestMapping annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513031/multiple-spring-requestmapping-annotations)), can I get the requested value(URL)?

Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/center", "/left"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCenter(Model model) throws Exception {     
    String requestedValue = getRequestedValue();  // I want this.

    // I want to do something like this with requested value.
    String result; 
    if (requestedValue.equals("center")
        result = "center";
    else if (requestedValue.equals("left")
        result = "left";
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As a newbie, I'm wondering is how "Model model" value is received from GET request, because Get mapping accepts only Url and some headers from UI. Can you tell me the reaon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Spring 3.1.0, you can use [URI Template Patterns with Regular Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex).

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/{path:[a-z-]+}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCenter(@PathVariable String path) throws Exception {             
    // "path" is what I want
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can have the Request (`HttpServletRequest`) itself as an parameter of the handler method. So you can then inspect the request url to get the "value".

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/center", "/left"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCenter(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {             
   String whatYouCallValue = request.getServletPath(); 
   ....
```

Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath--

*Btw: if I understand you right, you want to have different urls, not different values.*

Comment: Thanks it works. I called it values because the name of property is value, but now I think it could be confusing. I'll correct some.

Answer (score 4):

From Spring 3.1.0, you can use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/center", "/left"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCenter(Model model) throws Exception {     
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest();
        String requestedValue = builder.buildAndExpand().getPath();  // I want this.
        System.out.println(requestedValue);
        // I want to do something like this with requested value.
        String result="fail"; 
        if (requestedValue.equals("center"))
            result = "center";
        else if (requestedValue.equals("left"))
            result = "left";
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want.  i don't want to mess up the API mapping definition with something that is internal.

Comment: `ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequest(HttpServletRequest request)` worked fine in interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

Use RequestParam annotation. You can also add a parameter of type HttpServletRequest to your method and then getParameters from that.

Comment: It seams that Sangdol mean different urls, not http values. (So his term "values" is a bit confusing)

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the best answer @Hugh_Lee:
This method will work for all not mapped requests. If you want to use this method just for two (or several) cases only, e.g. "/center" and "/left", you may do following. Rename "center" to "positionCenter", "left" to "positionLeft" (or add another common word). So the code would be like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/{path:position+[A-Za-z-]+}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCenter(@PathVariable String path) throws Exception {             
    // "path" is what I want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following regex will make your method to be executed only for the urls `/center` and `/left`. And you can get the value with `@PathVariable` annotation.

```
@GetMapping("/{path:^center$|^left$}")
public ResponseEntity<?> whatIsThePath(@PathVariable String path){
    // path is either "center" or "left"
}
```