# Configuring multiple requestmapping in Spring framework

Tags: spring

I have a small issue in request mapping,

I have `controllerA` with request mapping as

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"login/formA.html", "B/formB.html", "C/formC.html"})
public class ControllerA {
}
```

I need to create one more controller without disturbing the existing controller,

request mapping for secound controller like below

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"X/test1", "Y/test2", "Z/test3"})
public class ControllerB {
}
```

How can I configure the `spring-servlet.xml` to configure the above scenario and to make it work.

I have the `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/public/login/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/public/signout/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/public/X/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My `spring-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.abc.xyz.controller"/>

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.abc.xyz.controller.example1"/>    

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

    <bean class='org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver' p:order='1'>
            <property name='mediaTypes'>
                  <map>
                        <entry key='json' value='application/json' />
                        <entry key='html' value='text/html' />
                  </map>
            </property>

            <property name='viewResolvers'>
                  <list>
                        <bean class='org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver' />
                        <bean class='org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver'>
                              <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
                              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
                              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
                        </bean>
                  </list>
            </property>


      </bean>
```

Plese do give me suggestion to resolve this issue , struck with few days.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513031/multiple-spring-requestmapping-annotations

Comment: If it is not related above link . please provide clarity in your question

Answer (score 0):

Add one more servlet mapping in web.xml like given below

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/public/*/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you krish for the response. But i have to map the directory also because , some scenarious like if login1/login, signout/signout two mappings then if you try the above configuration even if we make a call like login1/signout , i think the request will work, i dont want that behaviour , if the directory in web.xml mathces the directory in requestmapping in controller then only that called method need to invoke. For ex: web.xml, url-pattern is /public/view1 /* and /secured/showmessage/* and the request mapping like view1/viewService and showmessage/messageDispathcer, i hope got scenario.