# Can we have more than one @Path annotation for same REST method

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Can we have more than one `@Path` annotation for same REST method i.e. the method executed is the same, but it is executed on accessing more than one URL?

E.g.: I want to run the `searchNames()` method on both `http://a/b/c` and `http://a/b`.

Comment: Which programming language and framework are you using?

Comment: I am using Java and Jersey framework.

Comment: Could you describe the problem in more details? Because from your description looks like you're trying to solve the problem which you shouldn't have in the first place.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can't have mutliple `@Path` annotations on a single method. It causes a "duplicate annotation" syntax error.

However, there's a number of ways you can effectively map two paths to a method.

### Regular expressions in @Path annotation

The `@Path` annotation in JAX-RS accepts parameters, whose values can be restricted using regular expressions.

This annotation:

`@Path("a/{parameter: path1|path2}")`

would enable the method to be reached by requests for both `/a/path1` and `/a/path2`. If you need to work with subpaths, escape slashes: `{a:path1\\/subPath1|path2\\/subPath2}`

### Serving responses with a redirection status code

Alternatively, you could set up a redirection. Here's a way to do it in Jersey (the reference implementation of JAX-RS), by defining another subresource. This is just an example, if you prefer a different way of handling redirections, feel free to use it.

```
@Path("basepath")
public class YourBaseResource {

  //this gets injected after the class is instantiated by Jersey    
  @Context
  UriInfo uriInfo; 

  @Path("a/b")
  @GET
  public Responce method1(){
    return Response.ok("blah blah").build();
  }

  @Path("a/b/c")
  @GET
  public Response method2(){
    UriBuilder addressBuilder = uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder();
    addressBuilder.path("a/b");
    return Response.seeOther(addressBuilder.build()).build();
  }

}
```

### Using a servlet filter to rewrite URLs

If you're going to need such functionality often, I suggest intercepting the incoming requests using a servlet filter and rewriting the paths on the fly. This should help you keep all redirections in one place. Ideally, you could use a ready library. [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) can do the trick, as long as you're fine with a BSD license (check out their google code site for details)

Another option is to handle this with a proxy set up in front of your Java app. You can set up an Apache server to offer basic caching and rewrite rules without complicating your Java code.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Regular expressions in @Path would not work as one of the path contains a slash. Redirection would send status 303, but I want 200 (same for both). Will try the servlet filter approach.

Comment: You can use slashes in @Path regular expressions

Comment: @Jonas good to know. Do the slashes matched by regular expressions take precedence over the ones separating path segments? Personally, I wouldn't implement it this way. It would make the code harder to understand.

Comment: @Tom Have you tried the example you provided in second solution? First, `Response.ok` or `Response.seeOther` return `Response.ResponseBuilder` object, you should add `.build()` to return `Response`. Even after I added, this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Cacheing not this specific snippet. You're right, the `build()` call is missing. What happens when you add it? What do you mean by "doesn't work for me"?

Comment: @Tom When I curl the `a/b/c` path, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Cacheing it should return a 303 status code and set a `Location` header in the response but there will be no response body. What happens when you call it with `curl -I` ?

Comment: @Tom I see, I saw a 303 in the response header.

Comment: @Cacheing try it in a browser then, it should follow the redirect. Let me know if it works. Running `curl` with the `-L` option should also do the trick.

Answer (score 21):

As explained in [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17002237/2916086), you can not use more than one `@Path` annotation on a single method, because you will run into `error: duplicate annotation` at compile time.

I think the simplest way to get around this is to use method overloading:

```
@Path("{foo}")
public Response rest(@PathParam("foo") final String foo) {
    return this.rest(foo, "");
}

@Path("{foo}/{bar}")
public Response rest(@PathParam("foo") final String foo,
                     @PathParam("bar") final String bar) {
    return Response.ok(foo + " " + bar).build();
}
```

You could also use more different method names if you run into the case where multiple overloaded methods have the signature.

Answer (score 12):

Another solution for your particular example:

- http://a/b/c
- http://a/b

Let's suppose that:

- `/a` is for the resource class
- `/b/c` and `/b` are the paths for the methods

because a full path looks like:

`<protocol><host><port><app><url-pattern><resource-path><method-path>`.

**Use optional parameter**

```
@Path("/b{c : (/c)?}")
public Response searchNames(@PathParam("c") String val) {
    ...
}
```

The example above works for all examples like:

- `/b`
- `/b/`
- `/b/c`
- `/b/c/`

but when `c` is provided, the `val` is `/c` (it has a `/` before).

If you want to fix the problem above (to avoid Java parsing), you need something more complex:

```
@Path("/b{slash : (/)?}{c:((?<=/).*)?}")
```

which will return only `c` (not `/c`) for the 3<sup>rd</sup> bullet point, but for the 4<sup>th</sup> bullet point it will return `c/` which has to be parsed in Java.

But for your case (*"the method executed is the same"*), don't worry about parsing because you don't have different actions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Spring then try

`@RequestMapping(value = {"/def", "/abc"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)`

This will [work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2513031/32453) for both /abc and /def.

– [sSaroj](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47347626/32453) Nov 17 '17 at 10:13