# RESTful service on overloading method in WebLogic

Tags: java, rest, ejb, weblogic, overloading

I am using **WebLogic 12.1.2**. (It seems to be a WebLogic issue because the same code works fine under **JBoss**)

I have an EJB with overloading methods. If I assign both method with same RESTful path, the deployment on WebLogic will appear to be success but fail when I access the EJB method with this message:

```
Root cause of ServletException.
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
```

Here is my EJB code:

```
  @Stateless
  @LocalBean
  @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
  @Path("/License")
  public class License implements LicenseRemote, LicenseLocal {

  public License() {
  }

  @POST
  @Path("/registerTerminal")
  @Produces("application/json")
  public ResultRecord registerTerminal(
        @QueryParam("machineName") String machineName,
        @QueryParam("computerName") String computerName,
        @QueryParam("terminalId") String terminalId) {

    ..............
    ...............
    ...............
  }

  @POST
  @Path("/registerTerminal")
  @Produces("application/json")
  public TerminalInfo registerTerminal(
        @QueryParam("terminalId") String terminalId) {

    ..............
    ...............
    ...............

  }
```

If I change one of the Path annotation to different value, then everything works fine.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You will probably find this info useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000193/can-we-have-more-than-one-path-annotation-for-same-rest-method

Comment: Thanks...I was using a similar workaround like the link in your post suggested, but just trying to find a cleaner way