# Can I have 2 different path for 1 class in Rest Api?

Tags: java, rest, api

I want a single API in a class to be accessible from 2 different paths.

For example: An API like **getUsers** should be accessible from **/a/b/c/getUsers** and as well as from **/a/b/c/Users/getUsers**.

I tried to use the placeholders using **|** symbol but I don't want placeholders since it Users is in the path for other APIs in other class.

Can someone please provide any solution for the same using @Path annotation in Java.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place? If one form is an old variant, wouldn't path rewriting be the better alternative?

Comment: What is the purpose of that? Why not picking 1 approach?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000193/can-we-have-more-than-one-path-annotation-for-same-rest-method

Comment: If you are using Spring then try @RequestMapping(value = {"/def", "/abc"}, method = RequestMethod.POST). This will work for both /abc and /def.