# Multiple @RequestMapping for a method in controller class in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a method in controller class in Spring MVC.

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
    public void contactHomeDispatcher(){
    ...
    }
```

Is it possible to map another url for this method say "/contact". My question is whether it is possible to have multiple request mappings for a single method in a controller.

Comment: Under what condition will you need this?

Comment: Can need it in an multi tenant app or other user case when you want same functionality but different URL @vincent-ramdhanie In servlet that is why they have servlet mapping besides servlet decleration

Comment: Duplicate to: [Multiple Spring @RequestMapping annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513031/multiple-spring-requestmapping-annotations)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cannot have multiple `@RequestMapping`s, but you can have `@RequestMapping`s with multiple values of attributes:

```
@RequestMapping({ "/home", "/contact" })
```

[As you can see](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html), all attrbiutes of `@RequestMapping` are arrays, therefore they can take multiple values.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot. One more request. How can I add one more mapping in below method<br>
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: got it...no need to reply

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to above, you can declare @RequestMapping in the below format.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/aaa", "/bbb"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
```