# How to develop a REST Webservice method which accepts multiple URI

Tags: java, rest

How to develop a REST Webservice method which accepts multiple URIs for example

If we have a method

```
@RequestMapping(/add)
 public Response add(@RequestParam List elements){
  }
```

The method above serves for URL https://local host:8080/add

1. I have asked in interview how do we have a single Webservice which serves multiple URIs which I was not able to answer as I thought we should have unique URIs for each method
2. A follow up to this how do we have a method which returns the format whatever choosen (JSON, XML, PLAIN TEXT) from postman client.

Comment: Please take a look on [Multiple Spring @RequestMapping annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513031/multiple-spring-requestmapping-annotations)

Comment: You should be able to use `@RequestMapping(path={"/add", "/delete"})` and you can include `produces={"application/json", "text/xml"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify URI:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE
            })
public Response add(@RequestParam List elements){

}
```

Comment: Do we need to add all the mediatypes one by one. Dont we have a single option like MediaType.ALL or MediaType.Any

Comment: For all types, remove "produces". I thought you needed it

Comment: So if I remove produces, then it accepts any Mediatype from postman client

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use `consumes` to define what type of data you want to accept

Comment: No I want to accept any kind of data. Should I use produces or consumes

Comment: `consumes` => Data received from user. `produces` => Data sent to usere. If you want accept any data, remove `consumes`

Answer (score 0):

For the first question there is many ways to do that
**Spring restTemplate** can allow you to call a rest service in another method so all you have to do is to call your rest service when another uri is requested
You can also use proxies (web server proxies) to map same webservice to many URIs

For the second one you need to pass format as parameter and call specific service linked to format when executing

Hope that helps